# Sed command not work in Tcl script but OK in shell

Tags: sed, tcl

The task is to search certain keyword then goto next line, replace last two numbers/strings within braces, with other numbers/strings.
Text file content is like:
"

> test text Some_Text_Pattern
> { 7.315e-12 3.261963e-11 1.454601e-10 6.486475e-10 2.8925e-09 }
> some other test text Some_Text_Pattern
> { 7.315e-12 3.261963e-11 1.454601e-10 6.486475e-10 2.8925e-09 }

The command I'm using are like:

```
  foreach f $files {
    # Below is a complex version which I want to use but failed
    exec /bin/sh -c "sed '/Some_Text_Pattern\\/{n; s/[0-9.]\+[eE\][+-][0-9]\+\s*[0-9.]\+[eE][+-][0-9]\+\s*\}/1.000e-9 3.000e-9 \} /}' ${dir}/{f}.txt"
  }
```

Errors are all kinds. Latest one says:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 41: unknown command: `['
> while executing "exec /bin/sh -c "sed '/constraint_explicit_points_slew\/{n;
> s/[0-9.]+[eE][+-][0-9]+\s*[0-9.]+[eE][+-][0-9]+\s*}/1.000e-9 3.000e-..."
> ("foreach" body line 3)

Answer (score 1):

One solution I got:

```
exec sed -i {/Some_Text_Pattern\\/{n; s/[0-9.]\+[eE\][+-][0-9]\+\s*[0-9.]\+[eE][+-][0-9]\+\s*\}/1.000e-9 3.000e-9\}/}} ${file}
```

Seems using shell command in Tcl is more complicated.

Comment: It's not more complicated. Just a different syntax; `{...}` in Tcl is like `'...'` in Shell except it nests properly. That's virtually always what you want.

Comment: Yes. I've searched and used different answer. But to make the shell version work is harder somehow. Probably due to hard to make the single quote pairs correctly or something else cause I need quotes inserted.